# Difference between R's sum() and Armadillo's accu()

Tags: c++, r, precision, rcpp, armadillo

There are small differences in the results of R's `sum()` function and RcppArmadillo's `accu()` function when given the same input. For example, the following code:

R:

```
vec <- runif(100, 0, 0.00001)
accu(vec)
sum(vec)
```

C++:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double accu(arma::vec& obj)
{
    return arma::accu(obj);
}
```

Gives the results:

> 0.00047941851844312633 (C++)
>
> 0.00047941851844312628 (R)

According to http://keisan.casio.com/calculator the true answer is:

> 4.79418518443126270948E-4

These small differences add up in my algorithm and significantly affect the way it executes. Is there a way to more accurately sum up vectors in C++? Or at least to get the same results that R does without having to call R code?

Comment: Well at least in this particular case the C++ code seems to be *more accurate* than the R code (assuming the result of the online tool is a reliable gold standard, which I’m not convinced of) so do you know for a fact that using C++ here negatively impacts your accuracy?

Comment: [You may find the R `.Machine` doc useful](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/zMachine.html)

Comment: Assuming the online tool is correct, the R code is more accurate. The first number give was from c++, and the second is from R. In the end my algorithm converges on the same results either way. The difference is in the number of iterations it takes to get there. Sometimes the difference in number of iterations is in the 100s.

Comment: I think you should make your example more reproducible by calling `set.seed` before `runif` so that others can check against the same test case. And can you also include the code for your `log` function?

Comment: To accompany your last edit, [`sum`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/summary.c#L115) indeed, seems to store the summation in a type defined [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/include/Defn.h#L1386)

Comment: I think you should post your edit as an answer (and accept it if it solves your problem the best) instead of editing your question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**What I have found:**

I successfully managed to write a function which is able to mimic R's sum function. It appears R uses a higher precision variable to store the results of each addition operation.

What I wrote:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double accu2(arma::vec& obj)
{
    long double result = 0;
    for (auto iter = obj.begin(); iter != obj.end(); ++iter)
    {
        result += *iter;
    }
    return result;
}
```

How it compares in speed:

```
set.seed(123)
vec <- runif(50000, 0, 0.000001)
microbenchmark(
  sum(vec),
  accu(vec),
  accu2(vec)
)


       expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
   sum(vec) 72.155 72.351 72.61018 72.6755 72.7485 75.068   100
  accu(vec) 48.275 48.545 48.84046 48.7675 48.9975 52.128   100
 accu2(vec) 69.087 69.409 70.80095 69.6275 69.8275 182.955  100
```

So, my c++ solution is still faster than R's sum, however it is significantly slower than armadillo's accu()

Comment: For benchmarking I don't usually print out this many digits. The only reason I did here is because I had the option to do so set earlier (for testing solutions to my problem)

Comment: Done. I think it's cool that you comment on all the questions I tag with Rcpp, even if it is to nag, haha

Comment: Note that `sum` does some checks as well as explicit `NA` handling, which explains why it is slower.

Answer (score 16):

**update**: based on what others have found in the source, I was wrong about this - `sum()` *does not sort*. The patterns of consistency I found below stem from the fact that sorting (as done in some cases below) and using extended-precision intermediate values (as done in `sum()`) can have similar effects on precision ...

@user2357112 comments below:

> [src/main/summary.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/main/summary.c) ... doesn't do any sorting. (That'd be a lot of expense to add to a summation operation.) It's not even using pairwise or compensated summation; it just naively adds everything up left to right in an LDOUBLE (either long double or double, depending on HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE).

I have exhausted myself looking for this in the R source code (without success - `sum` is hard to search for), but <s>I can show by experiment that when executing `sum()`, R sorts the input vector from smallest to largest in order to maximize accuracy</s>; the difference between `sum()` and `Reduce()` results below is due to use of extended precision.  I don't know what `accu` does ...

```
 set.seed(101)
 vec <- runif(100, 0, 0.00001)
 options(digits=20)
 (s1 <- sum(vec))
 ## [1] 0.00052502325481269514554
```

Using `Reduce("+",...)` just adds the elements *in order*.

```
 (s2 <- Reduce("+",sort(vec)))
 ## [1] 0.00052502325481269514554
 (s3 <- Reduce("+",vec))
 ## [1] 0.00052502325481269503712
 identical(s1,s2)  ## TRUE
```

`?sum()` also says

> Where possible extended-precision accumulators are used, but this is platform-dependent.

Doing this in `RcppArmadillo` on the sorted vector gives the same answer as in R; doing it on the vector in the original order gives yet a different answer (I don't know why; my guess would be the aforementioned extended-precision accumulators, which would affect the numerical outcome more when the data are unsorted).

```
suppressMessages(require(inline))
code <- '
   arma::vec ax = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(x);
   return Rcpp::wrap(arma::accu(ax));
 '
## create the compiled function
armasum <- cxxfunction(signature(x="numeric"),
                        code,plugin="RcppArmadillo")
(s4 <- armasum(vec))
## [1] 0.00052502325481269525396
(s5 <- armasum(sort(vec)))
## [1] 0.00052502325481269514554
identical(s1,s5)  ## TRUE
```

But as pointed out in comments this doesn't work for all seeds: in this case the `Reduce()` result is *closer* to the results of `sum()`

```
set.seed(123)
vec2 <- runif(50000,0,0.000001)
s4 <- sum(vec2); s5 <- Reduce("+",sort(vec2))
s6 <- Reduce("+",vec2); s7 <- armasum(sort(vec2))
rbind(s4,s5,s6,s7)
##                       [,1]
## s4 0.024869900535651481843
## s5 0.024869900535651658785
## s6 0.024869900535651523477
## s7 0.024869900535651343065
```

I'm stumped here.  I would have expected at least `s6` and `s7` to be identical ...

I will point out that in general when your algorithm depends on these kinds of tiny numeric differences you're likely to be getting very frustrated, as the results are likely to differ on the basis of many small and possibly-out-of-your-control factors like particular operating system, compiler, etc. you work with.

Comment: I tried sorting and running accu however, I am not getting the same results as you. Example:

set.seed(123)

vec <- runif(50000, 0, 0.000001)

sum(vec) # 0.024869900535651482

accu(sort(vec)) # 0.024869900535651343

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I don't know how to make code look good in a comment

Comment: you have to use the same random-number seed ... try `set.seed(101)` instead of `set.seed(123)`

Comment: But if it only works with certain seeds, then how do we know the similarity isn't by chance?

Comment: I found the source. It's in [`src/main/summary.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/main/summary.c), and it doesn't do any sorting. (That'd be a lot of expense to add to a summation operation.) It's not even using pairwise or compensated summation; it just naively adds everything up left to right in an `LDOUBLE` (either `long double` or `double`, depending on `HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE`).

Comment: Actually, it looks like alexis_laz already posted the source a few hours ago in a comment up above.

Answer (score 4):

you could use the `mpfr` package (Multiple Precision Floating-Point Reliable) and specify the decimal point

```
 library("Rmpfr")
 set.seed(1)
 vec <- runif(100, 0, 0.00001)
#      [1] 2.655087e-06 3.721239e-06 5.728534e-06 9.082078e-06 2.016819e-06 8.983897e-06 9.446753e-06 6.607978e-06 6.291140e-06 6.178627e-07 2.059746e-06
#     [12] 1.765568e-06 6.870228e-06 3.841037e-06 7.698414e-06 4.976992e-06 7.176185e-06 9.919061e-06 3.800352e-06 7.774452e-06 9.347052e-06 2.121425e-06
#     [23] 6.516738e-06 1.255551e-06 2.672207e-06 3.861141e-06 1.339033e-07 3.823880e-06 8.696908e-06 3.403490e-06 4.820801e-06 5.995658e-06 4.935413e-06
#    [34] 1.862176e-06 8.273733e-06 6.684667e-06 7.942399e-06 1.079436e-06 7.237109e-06 4.112744e-06 8.209463e-06 6.470602e-06 7.829328e-06 5.530363e-06
#     [45] 5.297196e-06 7.893562e-06 2.333120e-07 4.772301e-06 7.323137e-06 6.927316e-06 4.776196e-06 8.612095e-06 4.380971e-06 2.447973e-06 7.067905e-07
#     [56] 9.946616e-07 3.162717e-06 5.186343e-06 6.620051e-06 4.068302e-06 9.128759e-06 2.936034e-06 4.590657e-06 3.323947e-06 6.508705e-06 2.580168e-06
#     [67] 4.785452e-06 7.663107e-06 8.424691e-07 8.753213e-06 3.390729e-06 8.394404e-06 3.466835e-06 3.337749e-06 4.763512e-06 8.921983e-06 8.643395e-06
#     [78] 3.899895e-06 7.773207e-06 9.606180e-06 4.346595e-06 7.125147e-06 3.999944e-06 3.253522e-06 7.570871e-06 2.026923e-06 7.111212e-06 1.216919e-06
#     [89] 2.454885e-06 1.433044e-06 2.396294e-06 5.893438e-07 6.422883e-06 8.762692e-06 7.789147e-06 7.973088e-06 4.552745e-06 4.100841e-06 8.108702e-06
#     [100] 6.049333e-06


sum(mpfr(vec,10))
#    1 'mpfr' number of precision  53   bits 
#    [1] 0.00051783234812319279
```

Comment: I think OP prefers performing the operation in C++. Luckily high-precision arithmetic libraries, in particular MPFR, also exist for C++.

Comment: Konrad is correct about me preferring the operation in C++. That is cool that this library exists in c++. I'll check it out. Another point which is worth considering is the time it takes to execute the operation. So it would also be great if I didn't need to do any expensive conversion operations away from armadillo objects