# Obtaining different results from sum() and '+'

Tags: r, sum

Below is my experiment:

```
> xx = 293.62882204364098
> yy = 0.086783439604999998
> print(xx + yy, 20)
[1] 293.71560548324595175
> print(sum(c(xx,yy)), 20)
[1] 293.71560548324600859
```

It is strange to me that `sum()` and `+` giving different results when both are applied to the same numbers.

Is this result expected?

How can I get the same result?

Which one is most efficient?

Comment: Relevant SO question + answer re floating point number precision: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: Interesting to note that `sum(xx,yy)` is the same as `xx+yy`. Also `Reduce(\`+\`, c(xx,yy))`. It's just `sum(c(xx,yy))` that's the odd man out.

Comment: But should not this precision impact both `sum` and `+` in same way? What is really different between those 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [r-devel thread here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-March/075710.html) that includes some detailed description of the implementation. In particular, [from Tomas Kalibera](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-March/075719.html):

> R uses long double type for the accumulator (on platforms where it is
> available). This is also mentioned in ?sum:
> "Where possible extended-precision accumulators are used, typically well
> supported with C99 and newer, but possibly platform-dependent."

This would imply that `sum()` is more accurate, although this comes with a giant flashing warning sign that if this level of accuracy is important to you, you should be **very worried** about the implementation of your calculations [in terms both of algorithms and underlying numerical implementations].

I answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589705/difference-between-rs-sum-and-armadillos-accu/38590421#38590421) where I eventually figured out (after some false starts) that the difference between `+` and `sum()` is due to the use of extended precision for `sum()`.

[This code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f9c955fc6699a1f0482e4281ba658215c0e0b949/src/main/summary.c#L857-L860) shows that the sums of individual elements (as in `sum(xx,yy)` are added together with `+` (in C), whereas [this code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f9c955fc6699a1f0482e4281ba658215c0e0b949/src/main/summary.c#L152-L170) is used to sum the individual components; line 154 (`LDOUBLE s=0.0`) shows that the accumulator is stored in extended precision (if available).

I believe that @JonSpring's timing results are *probably* explained (but would be happy to be corrected) by (1) `sum(xx,yy)` will have more processing, type-checking etc. than `+`; (2) `sum(c(xx,yy))` will be slightly slower than `sum(xx,yy)` because it works in extended precision.

Comment: The source code is actually a function called [do_summary](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f9c955fc6699a1f0482e4281ba658215c0e0b949/src/main/summary.c#L541). It handles `sum()`, `min()`, `max()` and `prod()`

Comment: I saw that but got confused ... thought it had something to do with `summary()`.

Comment: The translation from primitive name to c function name happens in [names.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/names.c). That would have made sense if `do_summary` was related to `summary()` but it turns out `summary.default` isn't a primitive function so all the work happens in R code, not C code.

Comment: Thanks. Then why `print(sum(c(xx,yy)), 20)` and `print(sum(xx,yy, 20)` are different?

Comment: `sum(xx,yy,20)` is equivalent to `sum(xx)+sum(yy)+20)`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like addition is 3x as fast as summing, but unless you're doing high-frequency trading I can't see a situation where this would be your timing bottleneck.

```
xx = 293.62882204364098
yy = 0.086783439604999998

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(xx + yy, sum(xx,yy), sum(c(xx, yy)))
Unit: nanoseconds
           expr min    lq   mean median    uq  max neval
        xx + yy  88 102.5 111.90  107.0 110.0  352   100
    sum(xx, yy) 201 211.0 256.57  218.5 232.5 2886   100
 sum(c(xx, yy)) 283 297.5 330.42  304.0 311.5 1944   100
```